# Disable Emacs text scaling

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to disable text Scaling in Emacs?
Whenever I reverse the undo direction (C-x C--), the text size decreases.
I am using Emacs 24 with Prelude on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @xfq's answer, you can turn off scaling by unsetting the key in your init file, or your .emacs file (available at ~/.emacs).

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-x C--"))
```

(*remember that you can reload the file without restarting emacs using* `M-x load-file .emacs` *when you're done editing*)

You can read more on these commands by typing `C-h f text-scale-adjust RET`. text-scale-adjust is bound to `C-x C-0`, and resets any scaling performed by `C-x C--` or `C-x C-+`, as explained in that page.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried (global-unset-key "/C-x/C--") but Emacs said that was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Try ***C-x C-0 0***.  It can reset the default face height to the global default.